# i want fetch nyt api

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I tried to fetch NYTimes API  but it gave me some error it says this.state.items.map is not a function

**here is console.log results**

[image]

**and here is code**

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=i have key"
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json =>
        this.setState({
          items: json
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    const Allitem = this.state.items.map(item => (
      <div>
        <h1> {item.results.byline}</h1>
      </div>
    ));

    return <div>{Allitem}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot, it appears the return result from the API is roughly:

```
{
  // Other data ...
  results: [
    // 39 objects
  ]
}
```

So with the current call:

```
this.setState({ items: json })
```

The `items` is now an object (not an array).

A simpler example is if you ran this in your browser console you would get the same error:

```
const json = {}
json.map(value => value)
// Uncaught TypeError: json.map is not a function
```

Try updating this call to be:

```
this.setState({ items: json.results })
```

I'm not able to test without an API key so basing this off your screenshot/code alone.

Here is an example of the full code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ }]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=i have key"
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json =>
        this.setState({
          items: json.results
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    const Allitem = this.state.items.map(item => (
      <div key={item.url}>
        <h1> {item.byline}</h1>
      </div>
    ));

    return <div>{Allitem}</div>;
  }
}
```

Also note that `key={item.url}` was added. You'll need a unique [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for each element. Preferably this would be an `id` but given that two articles can't be at the same `url` that seems like a potentially safe attribute.

Comment: I really appreciate that!!